# Change html extension to php

Tags: php, html

I changed my `.html` extension to `.php` but now the code is not executing, I only see the code in the navigator, but not the execution of this code. What should I do?

Comment: Sound like you are not running a webserver with PHP enabled.

Comment: I'm running in local, not using webserver

Comment: You can have a web server installed locally as well. You can use [PHP's built in webserver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). There are also more complete development environment you can install, like [WAMP](https://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/).

Comment: To clarify, had you Php code that did execute when your files had the .html extension, before renaming them?

Comment: Btw, do you have PHP installed at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check path for you .php file is correct or not i.e it is in correct directory with a localhost or webserver and also see if the  tag is there